# Circular,Elliptical and Arc motion in Universal Tween Engine

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, tween

I would like to use the universal tween engine in the LibGdx based Android Game. I would to know if there is any in-built function for the circular or elliptical motion in the universal tween library.

My requirement is just to move an object in the below mentioned path (to and Fro). I am trying achieve it using any inbuilt function. please advice if it is achievable

[image]

Comment: Try using waypoints, and define few points, to achieve this.

Comment: Thank Vljko. I finally applied little bit skew and got compromised

Comment: Glad it works for you.